# How can I force csproj files into Incredibuild?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, build, continuous-integration

I have a project that has a large number of .csproj files.  Xoreax explicitly doesn't support building these types of files and I'm not sure they intend too in the short term.  I've been looking to find a way to pre-process all these csproj files and create temporary sln files so that I can pass those into Incredibuild, but not having any luck.  It seemed like it should be possible using devenv and giving it the csproj, but it's not doing it.

So, I guess I'm looking to find a way to either open the csproj, create a temp sln file and save it then pass it to xoreax.  Or, take the list that we generate of the csproj files from the msbuild targets we have prior to them dealing with them in their own way, and force them into a temp sln file per target file (I beleive we have 6 separate target files).

Or any other helpful way to build csproj files within Incredibuild.  .Net CruisControl is what I'm using for CI, so if there's any other tricks for that (or that's an entirely differnet question to pose)